# Which measurements can I take using which programs to exploit the already low quality and save as much space as possible?

Tags: video, software-recommendation, video-quality, compression, recommendation

This is the best my actioncam can create.

[image: Rollei Wifi 5S]

My goal is to take advantage of this low quality and save as much harddrive space as possible so visible quality remains.

Which measurements can I take using which windows programs to exploit the already low quality and save as much space as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few video quality metrics available for you to use, primarily [SSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) and also [PSNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio). You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) to convert the video and then compare the output.

**Step 1** Convert the video

```
ffmpeg -i actioncamfile -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy -map 0 compressed.mp4
```

The CRF value modulates the quality. Lower values produce better quality but larger file sizes. Typical values range from 18 to 28, but absolute range is 0 to 51, but 0 being lossless, which will produce an exact looking file but will be bloated.

If you want to test with only a small section, say 20 seconds of the source starting from 15 seconds into the file, you can use

```
ffmpeg -ss 15 -i actioncamfile -t 20 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy -map 0 compressed.mp4
```

**Step 2** Measure the quality of the conversion

Run

```
ffmpeg -i compressed.mp4 -i actioncamfile -lavfi "ssim;[0:v][1:v]psnr" -f null -
```

This command output, at its end, will display lines like this

```
[Parsed_ssim_0 @ 000000000039ad80] SSIM Y:0.984483 U:0.980458 V:0.980921 All:0.983219 (17.751712)
[Parsed_psnr_1 @ 0000000000398320] PSNR y:42.63 u:43.19 v:44.09 average:42.90 min:42.07 max:46.16
```

You can aim for a SSIM `All` value to be at least 0.99, or set your own benchmark, based on what's acceptable.

Comment: For some reason, All: stays at 0.7 no matter what crf is like between 18 and 37. My commands: http://pastebin.com/asQrmmq0

Comment: Try without `-ss`

Comment: If you are just looking at SSIM to be over 0.99, do you need to include `;[0:v][1:v]psnr` in the command?